# Añadir URL en tab menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, tab

Alguien me puede ayudar con js??
Necesito que al escribir la url en cuestión se me abra el tab sin tener que hacer el click en el tab.
Algo asi (ejemplo: midominio.com/index.php#tab2 en este caso al escribir la ruta del tab 2 se me muestre el tab2) actualmente solo se me muestra si solo clico en el tab.
Dejo aqui mi codigo...

```html
<div class="tab mt-2">
    <button class="tablinks active" onclick="tabMenu(event, 'tab1'); window.location='#tab1';">Tab Menu 1</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="tabMenu(event, 'tab2'); window.location='#tab2';">Tab Menu 2</button>
</div>


    
<div id="tab1" style="display: block;" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>ver contenido Tab 1</h3>
</div>

<div id="tab2" style="display: none;" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>ver contenido Tab 2</h3>
</div>

<style>         
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;         
  background-color: #f2efef;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(154, 215, 255);
  
  
}

.tab button {  
  float: left; 
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


.tab button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(18, 118, 240);
  color: white;
}


.tab button.active {
  background-color: rgb(18, 118, 240);
  color:white;
}


.tabcontent {
  display: none;  
}

</style>

<script>
function tabMenu(evt, animalName) {
              let i, tabcontent, tablinks;
            
              // This is to clear the previous clicked content.
              tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
              for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
                tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
              }
            
              // Set the tab to be "active".
              tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
              for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
                tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
              }
              
            
              // Display the clicked tab and set it to active.
              document.getElementById(animalName).style.display = "block";
              evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
            }
            
</script>
```

**Gracias aprecio cualquier tipo de ayuda o sugerencia!**

Comment: En el `onload` de la web comprueba si tu URL acaba con `tabX`, si es así podrías simplemente usar findById del tabX en cuestión y simular un `click()` en él y ya está :) Lo que menciono puedes encontrar ejemplos funcionando aquí en StackOverflow directamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Mira esta manera de acerlo es muy similar
```

```js
window.addEventListener('hashchange',(ev) => {
  const url = ev.newURL.split('#')[1]
  const prevUrl = ev.oldURL.split('#')[1] || 'tab1'

  document.getElementById('to'+url).classList.add('active')
  document.getElementById(url).style.display = "block";
  if(!prevUrl) return;
  document.getElementById('to'+prevUrl).classList.remove('active')
  document.getElementById(prevUrl).style.display = "none";
});

window.onload = function (ev) {
  var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1) || 'tab1'; 
  document.getElementById('to'+hash).classList.add('active')
  document.getElementById(hash).style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;         
  background-color: #f2efef;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(154, 215, 255);
  
  
}

.tab a {  
  float: left; 
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


.tab a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(18, 118, 240);
  color: white;
}


.tab a.active {
  background-color: rgb(18, 118, 240);
  color:white;
}


.tabcontent {
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
    <div class="tab mt-2">
        <a class="tablinks" href="#tab1" id="totab1">Tab Menu 1</a>
        <a class="tablinks" href="#tab2" id="totab2">Tab Menu 2</a>
    </div>
    
    
        
    <div id="tab1" style="display: none;" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>ver contenido Tab 1</h3>
    </div>
    
    <div id="tab2" style="display: none;" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>ver contenido Tab 2</h3>
    </div>
```

Comment: No olvides [edit] tu respuesta y explicar _qué hace este código_.

Comment: Me sirvió fenómeno!!!! ;)

Comment: Si copio y pego la ruta midominio.com/index.php#tab2 no funciona.
Tiene que ejcutarse primero el tab1 para que funcione? hay alguna manera de solucionar eso?

Comment: a tu etiqueta <script> agregale defer <script defer>

Comment: ya funcionaba de antes compañero! tenia un display: block en tab1 en vez de display: none..
muchas gracias por su ayuda ;)